# Consulta SQL usando LIKE y valor de campo

Tags: sql, where, like

Tengo una tabla en SQLite3 (https://sqliteonline.com/)
Y me piden los siguiente:

--  Escriba una consulta que retorne los campos K0 y c16 para los registros de la tabla tbl1 para los que la columna c16 empieza por la misma letra de la columna K0.

El problema es que no sabría como hacer el LIKE usando el valor de otro campo.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente, pero no me funciona

```
SELECT K0, c16
from tbl1
where c16 LIKE '$K0%'
```

El código SQL de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
        K0  CHAR(1),
        K1  INT,
        c12 FLOAT,
        c13 INT,
        c14 DATE,
        c15 FLOAT,
        c16 CHAR(4)
        );
    INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES 
        ('E',1,273.08,600,'2016-12-31',0.21,'BDGD'),
        ('D',2,756.37,500,'2019-02-28',0.37,'BCCC'),
        ('E',3,305.43,100,'2017-05-21',0.21,'BAED'),
        ('D',4,662.69,800,'2017-03-26',0.23,'BGDD'),
        ('C',5,822.81,100,'2017-11-17',0.35,'GGFC'),
        ('A',6,391.42,300,'2018-05-15',0.22,'BFGB'),
        ('C',7,755.27,800,'2018-07-04',0.47,'GCDB'),
        ('E',8,302.86,700,'2016-12-22',0.14,'DFCC'),
        ('C',9,267.42,200,'2018-04-18',0.10,'DGCE'),
        ('A',10,816.51,600,'2019-04-25',0.40,'DAGC'),
        ('C',11,346.64,900,'2017-04-18',0.15,'FBBC'),
        ('B',12,999.72,800,'2016-11-09',0.26,'FCGD'),
        ('C',13,712.61,400,'2017-10-23',0.31,'EDDA'),
        ('E',14,832.44,800,'2016-11-22',0.39,'EGFD'),
        ('C',15,370.58,900,'2016-10-01',0.11,'GCDD'),
        ('B',16,283.40,600,'2019-04-11',0.14,'BDEE'),
        ('E',17,692.93,200,'2018-03-25',0.25,'BGGA'),
        ('A',18,142.99,100,'2017-02-12',0.48,'GGFD'),
        ('C',19,570.43,400,'2019-04-12',0.48,'FBEE'),
        ('A',20,938.16,300,'2016-09-12',0.19,'BECB'),
        ('B',21,409.34,400,'2019-04-29',0.23,'GFAE'),
        ('E',22,118.77,900,'2016-10-29',0.32,'GEFE'),
        ('E',23,325.15,200,'2019-04-21',0.19,'FBGC'),
        ('C',24,482.32,300,'2019-05-03',0.11,'CCCE'),
        ('E',25,600.90,700,'2018-11-07',0.36,'BBBA'),
        ('A',26,456.47,400,'2018-01-28',0.11,'FGED'),
        ('E',27,720.90,800,'2017-01-16',0.12,'FBGD'),
        ('B',28,326.45,700,'2017-07-27',0.36,'AGAA'),
        ('D',29,317.77,200,'2017-02-27',0.47,'GCEA'),
        ('A',30,135.80,900,'2017-01-26',0.23,'EGAB');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Bienvenido Carlos a Stack Overflow!
La consulta que te encontrabas realizando tiene un inconveniente, y es que al pasar como patrón `'$K0%'`, estás seleccione aquellos valores que comienzan por el valor `K0`, cosa que no tiene sentido.

Esta sería una manera de corregir tu problema:

```
SELECT K0, c16
FROM tbl1
WHERE c16 LIKE K0 || '%';
```

En este caso la consulta funcionará como tu esperabas que funcionara. El operador `||` se encarga de concatenar el valor que se encuentre en `K0` junto con el carácter `%`. Y ahora si por cada fila de la tabla seleccionaría aquellos registros de `c16` que empiecen por el mismo carácter de la fila `K0`.

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Aunque te dieron una respuesta valida, aca va otra, porque yo creo que tu ejercicio no es aprender a usar like, si no [substr](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-substr/)

Para ello, vamos a igualar el primer caracter de una, con el primer caracter de la otra

```
SELECT K0, c16
FROM tbl1
WHERE substr(c16,1,1) = substr(K0,1,1)
```

Tambienm se podria jugar con mayusculas y minusculas, usando la funcion upper por ejemplo...